# How to get Wifi working on Ubuntu 14.04 (Macbook Pro Retina 15 inch - 2014)

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, ethernet, macbook

I just downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 on my Macbook Pro Retina 15 inch 2014 version using usb. My problem is I can't get the Wifi working. No wifi connections would display on the wifi menu. I've tried searching for solutions all over the internet, but I could only find one solution, and that was using the Ethernet cable and downloading external software. Problem is, I currently don't have an ethernet cable, nor do I have a port to connect the ethernet cable (I live in a dorm). Basically, I have no way to connect to ethernet cable, yet need the wifi. Is there any way I could download the wifi driver probably using sudo-apt get? Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need an USB to Ethernet adapter and an Ethernet cable.

Comment: It's not trivial to get the hardware info for your computer. Please at least post the output of `lspci` or `lsusb` here. We need to know what wireless chipset you have. In all likelyhood, it's a Broadcom chipset that's not supported in the already outdated version of the Linux kernel shipped with Ubuntu.

Comment: In a jiffy, you could use a cheap wireless dongle. Realtek and Ralink (not branded as such though) ones are most likely supported.

Comment: Check out the instructions on copying the drivers in an USB (using another computer (or booting to OSX) http://cberner.com/2014/04/20/installing-ubuntu-14-04-on-macbook-pro-retina/

Answer (score 15):

You need to install `dkms` and `bcmwl-kernel-source`.

## Without internet connection

Both are located on the Ubuntu installation medium (possibly in different versions as reflected in the file names):

```
pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5_all.deb
pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Alternatively you can download the current versions:

1. Ask your friends to have them download the `.deb` files of the newest versions of the packages [`dkms`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/dkms) and [`bcmwl-kernel-source`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source). Both links lead to a list with the current versions of the respective package at the top for the right release (Trusty) and the right architecture (amd64).
2. Then copy these two files on your flash drive (1GB recommended).

Now, using the terminal, navigate to Desktop and type in this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i "drag one of the files here"
```

Then press enter. And click install if anything pops up. And you're done :)

## With internet connection

If you can somehow establish a internet connection (e. g. through a wired ethernet connection), you just need to install those package normally:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Comment: The command to install the .deb files is actually `dpkg`, not `dpgk`

Comment: @OSdave if you find a typo, suggest an edit to the post :)

Comment: @Zanna I tried, but _Edits must be at least 6 characters_

Comment: @OSdave ahh that's true, but you could just find some wording to change somewhere without changing the meaning... anyway I will fix this one.

Answer (score 2):

I have been endlessly trying to find the best solution of upgrading the Wi-Fi Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS drivers on my 2014 13.3" MacbookPro Retina and I have tried every possible solution - going onto different website and trying to install from the boot drive, or trying to get all kinds of files which would mimic the files described by the gentleman above.

The answer for all latest MacBook Pros(after 2014 december) is to follow the instructions above(many thanks), but make sure you downloads the LATEST version. I have used previous versions of the driver - and they failed.

[dkms](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/dkms)
[bcmwl-kernel-source](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source)

So, if you want to save about 4 hours of searching, then download the latest drivers and

```
sudo dpkg -i /filepath(drag and drop works as well)
```

Now you are good to go. Many thanks to the first publisher of the solution. It is his merit, but I just wanted to highlight the importance of his answer, as I was on the verge of abandoning Ubuntu and shifting to Mint after 4 hours of trying :) ( don't know why his answer was not highly rated)

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just ask around if there is an Ethernet connection available anywhere. if you find one: Connect an Ethernet cable with a live connection, then press ALT+F2 then type in update-manager then go to updates, then go to Notify me of a new version Then from the drop down press "For any new version", then press apply. You should receive a new version notification for 14.10. Update to this version. this should take about an hour. make sure you stay with your computer because there might be something to confirm during the update process. Once its finished and your computer has reboot, go to update-manager again. this time go to additional drivers. there should be one for your WiFi card. Choose the proprietary driver and then reboot. after the reboot, you should be able to connect to WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options

Option 1 - usnig wifi dongle

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer

Option 2 - but if you don't have internet connection

1 - Download [firmware-b43-installer](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/19e7y7w6ndozdzq/b43_updated.zip?dl=1&token_hash=AAEELVjeW3iSm3d0ScTg17BSplJ01qhPGCkhav5o9EYiJA&expiry=1400713892)

2 - copy it to an usb flash

3 - mount it on your ubuntu (and extract it to your Desktop)

4 - open up terminal

5 :

> sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/b43
>
> sudo cp Desktop/b43_updated.zip/*  /lib/firmware/b43
>
> sudo modprobe -rv b43
>
> sudo modprobe -v b43

hope to be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I looks through all the solutions here that recommend to download stuff and install this etc... but I found a simple solution.

The B43 Broadcom driver is on the CDROM, it just needs to be activated:

Go to `Settings -> Updates -> Additional drivers ->`you should see the Broadcom driver there and just activate it.

It worked for me: i did this 3 times on a Ubuntu USB drive and that was all I had to do.