# wifi doesn't work on Macbook pro 15 of ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, wireless, broadcom, macbook-pro

Searched around and still cannot solve the wifi issue.

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280
```

shows

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:43ba] (rev 01)
```

I installed `bcmwl-kernel-source` and also copied `brcmfmac43602-prie.bin` to `/lib/firmware/brcm/` folder. Doesn't solve the issue. I tried removed the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package but still no wifi.

Comment: You can try this solution for being able to install correct drivers for your wifi adapter: http://askubuntu.com/questions/513425/how-to-get-wifi-working-on-ubuntu-14-04-macbook-pro-retina-15-inch-2014.

Comment: You mean buy a wifi adapter?

Comment: Not speacially, you can connect a ethernet cable on your MacBook and try to catch a correct driver in "System Preference > Software and Updates > Additionnals drivers"

Comment: I don't have ethernet port on my MBP

Comment: @ycshao You can get ethernet-to-thunderbolt and ethernet-to-USB cables.  Also, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225216/driver-for-broadcom-14e443ba-chip ; you need to have Linux >= 3.17 with PCIE bus support enabled for brcmfmac to work.