# macbook 11,5 Wifi [14e4:43ba] doesn't work on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I installed ubuntu 14.04.02 on a new macbook pro 11,5 (15 inch), but wifi doesn't work.

Here are some information about the wifi adapter.

> $ lspci -nn | grep 0280
>    04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:43ba] (rev 01)
>
> $ sudo lshw -C Network 
>     *-network
>          description: Network controller
>          product: Broadcom Corporation
>          vendor: Broadcom Corporation
>          physical id: 0
>          bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
>          version: 01
>          width: 64 bits
>          clock: 33MHz
>          capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
>          configuration: driver=wl latency=0
>          resources: irq:18 memory:b0800000-b0807fff memory:b0400000-b07fffff

I followed the answers of the following questions, wifi still doesn't work. I tried many times, the final results are the same.

1. [wifi doesn't work on Macbook pro 15 of ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636218/wifi-doesnt-work-on-macbook-pro-15-of-ubuntu-14-04-lts)
2. [WIfi Issues with Macbook Pro Retina Early 2015 (12,2) on Ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622988/wifi-issues-with-macbook-pro-retina-early-2015-12-2-on-ubuntu-15-04/624746#624746?newreg=cc0241f003a24f8bb784547bcf4d3e87)
3. [How to get Wifi working on Ubuntu 14.04 (Macbook Pro Retina 15 inch - 2014)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/513425/how-to-get-wifi-working-on-ubuntu-14-04-macbook-pro-retina-15-inch-2014)

I didn't see the chipset id, but I think [14e4:43ba] should be the pid:vid of wifi adapter. I didn't see much discussion about this device. Hope anyone can share your experience of how do you get this work.

Thanks in advanced!

PS: I have a usb to ethernet adapter, I finished apt-get update and upgrade, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to uninstall wl driver by

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Copy [brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin) to /lib/firmware/brcm.

*But if you updated your system, this file should be already there in 14.04.*

Reboot and make sure that command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` gives output

```
Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac
```

Comment: Thanks! After updated the system, I can see brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin and brcmfmac43602-pcie.ap.bin under  /lib/firmware/brcm. But I didn't install bcmwl-kernel-source, and when I try to uninstall, I can see this log 'Package 'bcmwl-kernel-source' is not installed'. After reboot wifi driver is still not detected  `$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:43ba] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device [106b:0152]
05:00.0 Multimedia controller [0480]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:1570].`

Comment: Please post additional information to your question, not to comments. @Seinlin

Comment: This worked for me. I also copied over  brcmfmac43602-pcie.ap.bin just in case. Note, my macbook locks on shutdown and suspend. I suspect it may be due to these drivers.

Comment: Note that if you compile the kernel from source, you need to enable PCIE bus support.  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225216/driver-for-broadcom-14e443ba-chip

Answer (score 1):

You have to upgrade your Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And also install at least a 3.17 kernel ([Broadcom brcmsmac(PCIe) and brcmfmac(SDIO/USB) drivers](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/brcm80211/)):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

You can check your kernel version with:

```
uname -r
```

Reboot and the wifi adapter should be fine! (My wifi is working in a Macbook 11,5 - 2015 15" Retina)

Comment: Thanks, this got WiFi working on 14.04 on my 2015 Macbook Pro! Picking the driver in the Ubuntu software dialog never worked, but your commands did.

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade your kernel to the latest version. I used 4.1 with Linux Mint 17.2 on the MacBook Pro 13 early 2015 with the exact same chip. The device manager still shows a warning, but the driver works.