# 14.04 on Macbook Pro connecting to wireless

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager, macbook, macbook-pro

so I'm brand new to Linux and I just installed it as the single OS on my macbook pro. I'm having a problem where I can't connect to my home wifi network and I'm not sure what's wrong.

Just to tell you exactly what happens, I add a new 'hidden wifi network' via network settings, type the correct name and password (security is WPA/WPA2 personal), and hit connect. The little signal icon in the top right pulsates as if it's trying to connect, and after a while of that I get the 'disconnected' notification. If I go to network settings and look at the network name it says 'out of range' which is definitely not the case as I'm sitting right next to my router.

I've already done things suggested at [No Wireless When Install 14.04 on Macbook Pro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470153/no-wireless-when-install-14-04-on-macbook-pro) and [How to get Wifi working on Ubuntu 14.04 (Macbook Pro Retina 15 inch - 2014)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/513425/how-to-get-wifi-working-on-ubuntu-14-04-macbook-pro-retina-15-inch-2014), so I'm not sure what else to do. Could it be something to do with settings on my router? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I wasn't able to actually solve the problem, I just re-installed from the same install disk, re-followed the steps from link '1' in my original post and it seems to work fine now.

From user Wild Man at that link:

> Please do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

> Reboot

This seemed to work fine. I think the problem arose from me using the second set of steps Wild Man posted to use without an internet connection. The above steps are meant to be followed while connected via a wired connection.