# How to get Wifi working on Ubuntu 14.04 (Macbook Pro Retina 15 inch - 2014) followup

Tags: 14.04, apt, macbook

I am unable to get wifi working on my fresh install of Ubuntu on my Macbook Pro Retina.  I tried installing [`dkms`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/dkms) and [`bcmwl-kernel-source`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source) using `sudo dpkg -i <file>` following this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/555694/716793).  The installation failed because it ran into dependency problems ("dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration...")

**Edit 2**
For example, running `sudo dpkg -i '/media/usrname/STUFF/dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.9_all.deb'` yields this:

```
(Reading database ... 174321 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.9_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.9) over (2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu5.14.04.9) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dkms:
 dkms depends on module-init-tools; however:
  Package module-init-tools is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package dkms (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dkms
```

Various other answers suggest using `apt-get -f install` to get `APT` in a good state.  But this is not possible because I don't have internet to do this.

What can I do?

---

**Edit**

Running `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` yields this:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [106b:0134]
Kernel driver in use: wl
Kernel modules: bcma, wl
03:00.0 Multimedia controller [0480]: Broadcom Corporation 720p FaceTime HD Camera [14e4:1570]
```

Comment: If you have Ehternet available (or a USB tethered phone, etc.) I suggest you use that and install using APT.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. This will show the adapter. If you really need `wl`, there is an offline guide.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks for your extremely rapid response.  I just now managed to get it to work (answer below), but I have no understanding what-so-ever of why.

Comment: @Pilot6 I added the relevant info.  I don't know if might diagnose my earlier problems.

Comment: It doesn't. It would be more interesting to know what kind of dependency problems were there. Now it looks OK.

Comment: @Pilot6 Scrolling up in my terminal history I have the errors that were reported while trying `dpkg`.  See my edit again.

Comment: It looks like `dkms` was already installed. You could skip its installation. It is wierd and I never saw `module-init-tools` as a dependency of it. Maybe it is a non-standard Ubuntu iso. Funny that it needs a dependency to install the same package. Anyway your answer gives a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if I wave the magic wand like this,

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a --force-depends
```

everything works, and the wifi finds the all the networks.

Comment: Great that it works, but it is unclear what was the problem. Normally nothing is needed but dkms.

Comment: It would me more useful for readers if you add all steps you did to install the driver.