# Install Kubuntu on MacBook Pro late 2016

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, 17.04, macbook-pro, refind

I installed **kubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64** on a MacBook Pro Touch using almost all of the following [guide](https://linuxnewbieguide.org/how-to-install-linux-on-a-macintosh-computer/), except for installing rEFInd (version 0.11.0) for which I followed the [author's guide](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html).

Everything went well, I made several attempts, installing three distros (just for fun): KDE Neon, and Kubuntu Xenial and Zesty. The one currently installed is **kubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64**.

***The problem*** always remains the same: the WiFi card driver. I can not access the internet to make updates automatically, so I have to "ferry" packages by downloading them on a pendrive.

I followed [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/555694) correctly and [this too](https://askubuntu.com/a/773286), without any results. From the available network panel, you can see the router's WiFi network, enter the password access, but after a while, the password prompt reappears.

The best idea would be to use the interface Ethernet, alas ... there are only four USB Type C ports and an audio jack. I would not buy a C-Type Ethernet Ethernet Adapter now, I would first try to see if it could be done in another way.

---

As @Pilot9 requested in the comments:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list > out.txt
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [14e4:43ba] (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC [106b:015a]
        Kernel modules: brcmfmac, wl
04:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation DSL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 4C 2015] [8086:1578] (rev 02)
```

---

Addendum:

I tried to install manually following packages:

```
bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
coreutils_8.26-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb
dkms_2.3-3ubuntu1_all.deb
gcc_4%3a6.3.0-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
kmod_22-1.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libc-dev-bin_2.24-9ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb
libc6-dev_2.24-9ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb
libc6_2.24-9ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb
libgcc1_1%3a6.3.0-12ubuntu2_amd64.deb
linux-libc-dev_4.10.0-32.36_amd64.deb
make_4.1-9.1_amd64.deb
menu_2.1.47ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

all packages were installed successfully, but this didn't solved my problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: I don't have a solution; however, my MacBook Air (purchased in early 2015) works sporadically with WiFi -- sometimes it's fine, but sometimes it shows symptoms similar to yours. When it shows those symptoms, turning off the WiFi support and then re-enabling it usually gets it working. This might be worth trying, but if it's a consistent problem for you, I wouldn't hold out much hope that this will work. FWIW, I also see errors in the kernel ring buffer (`dmesg` shows this). I haven't done more to diagnose my problems because I seldom use that computer.